# Benchmarking approaches for fft algorithms

Tags: benchmarking, fft, fftw

I'm currently working on a library that has its own internal fft (Fast Fourier Transform) library which I would like to replace with [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/). Now, other developers are a bit concerned about the performance issues it might cause. Also the most critical part speed-wise is  the 1D convolution algorithm which deals with half-complex reals. (I'm using fftw's fftw_plan_r2r_1d).

Also, things are a bit more complicated because internally fftw uses different algorithms depending on the size of the transform.

My current idea is to generate a bunch of different length datasets. Then read them in and modify the dataset array for each iteration in a predetermined way before doing the transformation.

Or is there anything else I should know?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you generate an optimal plan for FFTW for each test case. The PATIENT and EXHAUSTIVE flags can result in faster plans, but they can take a significant amount of time to get there. (Obviously you shouldn't include this time in your benchmark timing as it's one off and cacheable.)

If you only need single precision input/output data then build the single precision version of the FFTW libraries - they can be quite a bit faster then the default double precision version and are plenty accurate enough for most appilcations in e.g. signal processing and image processing.

Also when building the FFTW libraries make sure you enable SIMD if appropriate for your architecture, e.g. SSE on x86 or AltiVec on PowerPC.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out my mixed radix fft routine, which is available from [my homepage](http://www.corix.dk/Mix-FFT/mix-fft.html). It includes a benchmark test program for both speed and accuracy that you may use for your evaluation.